# Ways to find out if the process is created by system (by pid) on macOS?

Tags: macos, pid, fuse, kernel-extension, vfs

I'm implementing API which allows to launch other apps (using NSTask) inside VFS (FUSE on macOS). After VFS is mounted a bunch of processes start accessing launched VFS in which my app works, and I'd like to implement some kind of filtering mechnism which will allow to detect whether process which is accessing the VFS is created by system (and potentially safe) or not, and if so it'll be granted an access to the file system where my app runs.

So far I'm able to get basic information of the process by it's pid. For example: process path, uid, ppid, code signature of the process etc (using Security framework, libproc etc)

I've done a couple of tests and see that there are process with uid != 0 and still critical for my app to run (if I deny access to them app which is started in VFS crashes) (e.g. /usr/libexec/secinitd, /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock), so looks like approach with filtering processes by pids, uids, ppids might not work.

So the question is: is it possible to distinguish whether process which is accessing my app was created by system and is potentially safe? I also don't want to do too much work by denying accees to critical system processes which will allow the app to successfully start and run in VFS.

Comment: I could answer with a simple "no," but that probably doesn't help you much. I'm still not entirely clear on what this "access" constitutes, and what exactly makes some apps "safe" and others not, and how exactly this relates to VFS/FUSE. Are you implementing a file system? Why have you tagged your question with the kernel-extension tag, where does a kext come into this?

Comment: In my case FUSE was used for custom file system which mounts local directory within which another application is running. By 'access' of the file system I mean any primitive operation like creation of the dir, access to file etc (my implementation is based on LoopbackFS provided by FUSE). The exact point is that I'm not sure what makes some apps "safe" and others not, my idea is that system ones (like secinitd, which is signed by apple) are safe and others are not (e.g. Google Chrome Helper.app, RescueTime.app etc start accessing my VFS).

Comment: I think pmdj is asking why you want to restrict processes? What would make a process "safe" from **your** point of view (not a technical description, a description of your purpose in restricting access). Or, put another way, why not let all processes access the file system? Why do normal permissions and ACLs not suffice?

Comment: Let's assume that files in VFS contain sensitive information and I'd like have several ways of protection against malicious attacks. So from this perspective process which neither reads nor modifes files within my filesystem is considered safe. Also another note worth mentioning is that files which are stored in VFS are encrypted. So if I let all processes access VFS how do I know that data inside of it will not be corrupted, stolen, removed etc?

Comment: Assuming you can rely on System Integrity Protection being enabled, you could check that the executable has the "restricted" flag (`SF_RESTRICTED`).

Comment: SIP is a good way to know if an executable is from Apple, but by the sound of it that doesn't satisfy your idea of safety. For example, `/bin/cp` is subject to SIP, and is signed by Apple, but anyone can use it to extract or corrupt a file, not just Apple. Similarly, Safari or Mail are extremely exposed for security purposes, so SIP doesn't really help there either.

Comment: I don't understand "So from this perspective process which neither reads nor modifes files within my filesystem is considered safe" - so in other words you only want to allow access to processes which don't actually access the files? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comment thread, your threat model is data theft via malware etc.

In this case, you can trust almost nothing, so the best way is probably to maintain an explicit whitelist of processes which are allowed to access your mount point, and block access to everything else by default. Log any processes to which access is denied, and allow the user to reverse that decision and add them to the whitelist. In other words, let the user decide what applications they consider safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your said that according to your inspection, there were several processes which were mandatory for the process to run, so why won't use try-and-error approach.

You deploy you FUSE drive on clean environment and record all processes that attempt to access your files - try to prevent each process and keep only those which crash your apps, and add them to a white-list.

Of course that this list is subject to change in different macOS versions, but it can give you the general idea.

Alternatively, you can break your app into couple of parts. for example, put the sensitive logic inside separated dylib file, and prevent access to this file only.. since dylib is not the main executable in your app, I believe fewer processes require mandatory access it.